# converting timestamp to fromnow() , moment showing 51 years fix value

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

giving output 51 years , i need in min ago , hours ago , days ago
using moment-timezone library

moment(1594747193).fromNow()

```
    <DropItem key={index} title="Crop">
    <span className="name-tag">KJ</span>
    <label className="label-name">
        <strong>Kishan Jaiswal </strong>
        {noti.message}
    </label>
    <span className="time">{moment(noti.created_at).fromNow()}</span>//here i m geeting output
    {console.log('noti.created_at', noti.created_at)}
    </DropItem>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: {moment(noti.created_at).fromNow()} , i have tried this

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Unix timestamp is this

```
noti.created_at =1594747193 * 1000
moment(noti.created_at).fromNow()
```